# npm ssh error doesn't replicate from shell

Tags: node.js, git, ssh, npm, docker

When trying npm install, I get error:

```
1206 error node v0.12.0
1207 error npm  v2.7.4
1208 error code 128
1209 error Command failed: git clone --template=/root/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror ssh://git@git.spindle.factfiber.com/schematist-postgres.git /root/.npm/_git-remotes/ssh-git-git-spindle-factfiber-com-schematist-postgres-git-8e4b2071
1209 error ssh: Could not resolve hostname git.spindle.factfiber.com: Name or service not known
```

However, when I try the very command reported from the shell:

```
git clone --template=/root/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror ssh://git@git.spindle.factfiber.com/schematist-postgres.git /root/.npm/_git-remotes/ssh-git-git-spindle-factfiber-com-schematist-postgres-git-8e4b2071
```

It works:

```
Cloning into bare repository '/root/.npm/_git-remotes/ssh-git-git-spindle-factfiber-com-schematist-postgres-git-8e4b2071'...
remote: Counting objects: 47, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (39/39), done.
remote: Total 47 (delta 20), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (47/47), 13.05 KiB, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (20/20), done.
```

I tried this a couple times in case it was a temp dns glitch. Does anyone know what could be happening?

**UPDATE**: when I create a new repo and

```
npm install git+ssh://git@git.spindle.factfiber.com:schematist-postgres.git
```

Then once it failed, 2nd time succeeded. Either way npm takes a really long time (20-30 secs?), while shell `git` succeeds in just a second.

This is a docker image, btw. I decided to throw in some command-line tools to an image (screen, jove) and rebuild -- before it was building fine, but still taking a really long time. So I don't think that just including those packages was the problem. The problem might be some DNS misconfiguration? But if so why is it npm specific?

**UPDATE** -- Dockerfile. This is being built on mac/yosemite

```
FROM debian:wheezy
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get update
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y curl wget \
  openssh-client build-essential unicode-data screen jove

# ------------------------------------------------
# node
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_0.12 | bash -
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y nodejs
RUN npm install -g coffee-script && npm -g install npm@latest

# ------------------------------------------------
# git
# setup keys so we can pull from github
# mounted "sw-pull-rsa" contains key

RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y git
ADD ./sw-pull-rsa /root/.ssh/id_rsa
ADD ./sw-pull-rsa.pub /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
RUN chmod 0600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN ssh-keyscan github.com >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts
RUN ssh-keyscan git.spindle.factfiber.com >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts

# ------------------------------------------------

RUN npm install -g npm
RUN npm install -g npm-cache

RUN mkdir -p /tmp/common 
COPY ./common/package.json /tmp/common/
RUN cd /tmp/common && npm install
```

Comment: can you post a reproducer, or at least your Dockerfile ? Do you always do `apt-get update` before `apt-get install` ?

Comment: I do `apt-get update` before install ... but not before every install. Do I need to? I could also consolidate install of npm and git. The first part is actually a base Dockerfile which I use for a few different things.

Answer (score 1):

Following up on @user2915097 -- placing an `apt-get update` before *every* install works. I think perhaps the git version and the npm version were not compatible in some way.